# photo gallery grab from 2nd table did not work

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 tables (sites and photo_gallery) in my database. First I display my posts from database, then it goes to my viewpost page.

Everything work file but in gallery portion my loop didn't work.

IN TOP of the page I use this code to run all viewpost pages.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    require_once("_includes/LocalHost.php");
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['id']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sites, photo_gallery WHERE gallery_con = photo_id AND id='$id' ";
    $result= mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Bad Query: $sql");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

In gallery portion

```
<?php

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $title = $row["title_post"];
        $imageURL = 'images/'.$row["photographs"];
        $imageThumbURL = 'images/thumb_'.$row["photographs"];

?>
  <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" class="image" data-fancybox="images">
      <img src="<?php echo $imageThumbURL; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" height="200px" />
  </a>

<?php }
}
?>
```

1 to 15 images with every post and it will display only one 2nd image.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your db schema I'm guessing the problem is that 'photo_gallery' table have 'id' and 'photographs' columns and insert the data on multiple rows with one id associated to your site (post). So when you are trying to select it together with the 'sites' table it will only pull one entry from the 'photographs' because there's only one row in the sites table.

You need another query to fetch the photographs from db in the while loop and loop the images and text in it (if that makes sense to you, if not I can change your code fast and write it here)